Referencing the semicolon key in script
I have the folowing code that works on AutoHotKey v1
AppsKey & `;::Send {Blind}{Right DownTemp}
AppsKey & `; up::Send {Blind}{Right Up}

However, this line causes trouble in AutoHotKey v2. How do i rewrite this line to accept AppsKey plus semicolon key in AutoHotKey v2?


For v2:
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0+

AppsKey & `;::Send "{Blind}{Right DownTemp}"
AppsKey & `; up::Send "{Blind}{Right Up}"

